# Taking high resolution photo from captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection

Tags: iphone, avfoundation

Currently `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` returns an image at 640x480 pixels from a `AVCaptureSession` of `AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480`.

The reason for a relative low-res AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 is I need to process the video frames. Lower resolution gives better speed.

At certain point, when I want to take a photo, I want a hi-res image. How can I tell `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` to return a higher than 640x480 image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You tell `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` to return a higher-resolution image by setting a higher-resolution preset.

Since 4.2, `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` will return approximately screen-sized video frames for `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`, which it sounds like would be ideal for your purposes. OTOH, in 4.1 and earlier it will return nothing. If you have to target 4.1 and earlier, you'll have to take the very slow way of changing the preset before capturing.